# Trouble importing csv-data within MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, variable-types

I am trying to read in a csv-file that contains daily data on EUR/USD exchange rates including the dates specifying year, month and day. The problem is that using readtable(filename) puts single quotes around all table-entries and therefore hinders me using the data at all.

Detect import options:

```
opts = detectImportOptions('EUR_USD Historische Data.csv');
```

Read in the data:

```
EUR_USD = readtable('EUR_USD Historische Data.csv');
```

Substract dates and transform to datetime variable:

```
dt = EUR_USD(:,1);
dates = datetime(dt,'InputFormat','yyyyMMdd'); 
% Does not work because of single quotes
```

I was able to subtract closing prices and make them workable, but I am not sure if this is an elegant way of doing so:

```
closing_prices = str2double(table2array(EUR_USD(:,5)));
```

Ultimately the goal is to make the data workable. I need to compare two columns with datetime-variables and if dates do not match between the two columns I need to remove that entry such that in the end both columns match.

This is the vector with dates:
[Dates vector wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOGqu.png)

I need it to look like this:
[Dates vector correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhTgl.png)

Comment: You could write a few commands above to remove the `'` character from your vector, and then load it into the `datetime` function.

Comment: Not sure what commands

Comment: Since [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) can use a string as an input, you could run a for loop before calling `datetime`, and remove the `'` chars by these commands inside your for loop: `string_val = dt(i,1); date_val = string_val(2:end-1);`

Comment: Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is remove the `'` character in order to read the data into `datetime` correctly. Look at the following example:

```
%stringz is the same as dt here: just the string data
T = table;
T.stringz = string(['''string1'''; '''string2'''; '''string3''']);
stringz = T.stringz;

%Run the for loop to remove the ' chars
for i = 1:length(stringz)
    strval = char(stringz(i,1));
    strval = strval(2:end-1);
    strmat(i,1) = string(strval);
end

%Then load data into datetime after this for loop
dates = datetime(strmat,'InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
```

`strmat` return a 3x1 string array with no `'` characters on the outside of the string.

Comment: Im still getting an error: Undefined function 'length' for input arguments of type 'table'.  Use the HEIGHT, WIDTH, or SIZE
functions instead.

Comment: Basically I used your code, but replaced stringz by my vector with dates in quotations

Comment: You may have to play around with it a bit since you didn't provide any data.

Comment: I also found that within MATLAB there is an option 'convert to categorical array' which appears to fix it as well. However if you do this with code instead of manually it gives me an error.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of a part of the vector